# Rebuild, Sync Gradle and Clean for just one Module with Android Studio

Tags: android, module, compilation, android-studio, project

I have in Android Studio a complex project establish by five modules. Four of them act as independent apps, but one of them is the base code for the rest. This way, I can have a big common core and four separates codes for every app (these apps share the shame model data and api connection).

My question is if it is possible rebuilding, cleaning or syncing just for one module, non the entire project in Android Studio.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nowadays with Android Studio you can use build -> make module “nameModule”

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to assign this ^ to a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 3):

sure, just use the project name when running Gradle, e.g. `gradlew :api:build`. This will build `api` module only.

More details [in the docs](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#multi_project_builds).

Comment: I run Gradle from the IDE Android Studio, just with the option 'Run'.

Comment: In the gradle modules tree you can run `build` under the needed module, it has the same effect.

Comment: But how can you rebuild just one module? I’m using Android Annotations Framework and in some cases I need to perform this action, but this action affects to all modules. Not just one.  And so it takes too much time.

Comment: In the projects tree just drill down to the module you want and run `build` from there.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem，search for Google，No answer direct question.

I find Android Studio Menu,find the method .

`Run` - > `Clean and Rerun"modle name"`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the addition the all of answer you can type a specific gradle task instead:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-tasks.html#gradle_tool_bar

[image]

In my case, Press `^ (macOS)` twice -> Type `gradle :your-specific-dfm:build`