# Android Studio and big amount of modules

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have project with nine modules:

[image]

Module app is *com.android.application*.

Other modules are *com.android.library*.

In module app I have many product flavors. Each of them have different set of connected modules.

---

My trouble it is build time. Is it possible to build/rebuild/clean/sync only modules, that connected in selected product flavor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711263/rebuild-sync-gradle-and-clean-for-just-one-module-with-android-studio

Comment: In this answer stated to build module manually, but I want that Gradle understood himself what modules to build for selected productFlavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a **maven repository** (private if it is a requirement).
In this way:

- each flavor in the app will use depedencies downloaded from the maven repo
- building the app will not force the rebuild of the modules
- update the module when you need and update the dependencies (using snapshots if you need them)